# Unable to declare environment variable using os.environ

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, nameerror

When I tried setting environment variable value:

```
import os
os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'] = 'Password123'
```

on PyCharm CE 2020.2, it does not even set the environment variable values for the duration of the Python process or child processes. It gives me the error:

```
DB_PASSWORD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'DB_PASSWORD' is not defined
```

Why is it so? What can be done to get this working without having to manually add the values?

Here's the screenshot to the error: https://the-inevitable-one.tumblr.com/image/627482222106165248

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is this literally all of the code? You don't have a call to `input` in there somewhere?

Comment: The error you've posted does not correspond to the code you've posted.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've added the screenshot for reference. I did declare the variable, so I don't have to call input.

Comment: Environment variables are not Python variables. You can't just type `DB_PASSWORD` into an interpreter prompt to access a `DB_PASSWORD` environment variable.

Comment: @larsks Do you mean that the error is generated by something else? I've attached the screenshot for reference.

Comment: Also Pycharm CE 2020.2 is NOT a version of Python - it is an IDE which can connect to a different versions of Python depending on the project. In future it will be more useful if you also state which verson of Python you are using in your current project (If you don't know you can find that by looking at the First line in the Python console within Pycharm).

Answer (score 1):

`os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'] = 'Password123'`

This line will export your `DB_PASSWORD` in environment.
Environment variables are not Python variables.

In pycharm, you have opened python interpreter which parses only python code.
It will look for `DB_PASSWORD` as python variable, not the system environment variable.

Try putting `DB_PASSWORD` into your command prompt `(cmd or shell)`,
or in python you can list env variables using

`print(os.environ)`